# How to create multiple themes in sass unsing sass modules feature?

Tags: css, sass, module, themes

Before modules were introduced to sass, you could make a themed stylesheet this way:

*themeDark.scss:*

```
$color: black;
```

*baseButton.scss:*

```
button {
  color: $color;
}
```

button.scss:

```
@import './_themeDark.scss'
@import './_baseButton.scss'
```

Now, modules were introduced to sass and `@import` is getting deprecated. How to achieve the same effect using sass modules?

Im looking for a solution, where some files are used as partial stylesheets. In the main file they are combined to form a final stylesheet that will be imported.

What i have tried:

- use `@use` instead of `@import`. It does not work, because variables from other modules are not seen.
- use mixins. The problem is that you have to pass all the variables through arguments and it is much harder to maintain than the solution above with `@import`.

Comment: Be aware that `@use` is currently only supported by Dart Sass.

Comment: I'm starting a project with Sass and I wanted to use this new syntax, but I have exactly the same problems as you explained. Can you told me how you solved that? Thank you.

Comment: @sevenlops right now im using both: `@use` and `@import` (for themes only) together. Hope, somebody could find a solution that would work after `@import` gets deprecated.

Comment: Are you able to set these values using CSS variables instead of baking them into the output with Sass?

Answer (score -1):

You can have scss map to store all themes

```
$themes: (
  theme1: (color: red),
  theme2: (color: orange),
  theme3: (color: yellow),
  theme4: (color: green),
  theme5: (color: blue)
);
```

Using this map is with an `@each` loop.

```
@each $theme, $map in $themes {
  .#{$theme} {
    color: map-get($map, color);
  }
}
```

On each loop, assign these values to `$theme` and `$map` respectively.

`$theme` - Theme name
`$map` - Map of all theme variables

You now use the `map-get()` function to get any theme variable from `$map` and output the correct property for each theme.

```
@each $theme, $map in $themes {
  .#{$theme} & { // <--- Notice the & here!
    color: map-get($map, color);
  }
}
```